# How do I get the correct id of this resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a has_many, through association between videos and topics with topicables as the independent resource. I want to have a link that **deletes that specific topicable record aka the association and NOT the video NOR the topic.**

I have this method in my topicables controller:

```
def destroy
  @topicable = Topicable.find(params[:id])
  @topicable.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to @video}
    format.js
  end
end
```

I call the above method with this link in my video show view:

```
<%= link_to "x", topicable_path(@topicable), :method => :delete, :class => 'topic_delete' %>
```

However, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TopicablesController#destroy

Couldn't find Topicable with ID=474
```

This is because 474 is the id of the video and not the id of the association between the topic and video in the topicable table. What is wrong with my `destroy` method above and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why is 474 the id of the video ? It should be the id of the association. What are the fields of your Topicable model ?

Comment: I know it should be the id of the association... but it's the id of the video. I have no idea why. The fields of the Topicable model are `video_id` `topic_id` and the primary key.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure about that, i would have to test some things, but can you try this please :

```
<%= link_to "x", @topicable, :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: no `@topicable` doesn't work. It's an object of Video and so it goes to the video controller destroy action and deletes the video.

Comment: It's not a video object if you do a find on Topicable model. At least that's what it should be. It's just that it's getting a video id that does not exist as a topicable object.

Comment: well if I change it to @topicable my destroy action in the videos controller is executed, which is not what I want.

Comment: how do you get @topicable in your link_to ?

Comment: any other ideas? there are no resources out there on how to delete associations in a has_many through association?

Comment: how do I get @topicable? I set it in the destroy method above.

Comment: i have done it many times, but without a delete method :/ (did it in a custom manner). It seems that you are passing a video object on @topicable though, and that can be the problem.